# How Can I Embed a Word Document in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to Embed the Word Document in silverlight,and i need to have all the same functionality of Word Document.
Like Cut,Copy,Paste,Save,Save us,Formating Etc.
How can i Achieve this?.
Also Suggest me some links too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SL4 comes with COM automation support mean if client machine has Word installed SL can use it to display work doc:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/185680/424357.aspx
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/MS-Word-Mail-Merge-with-Silverlight-4-COM-Automation.aspx

If you are using SL3.. it will be a little daunting... may be you will have to find some RTE to display word in it.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the COM model to read the file is that you must run the Silverlight app out of the browser with Elevated privileges and the user mush have Word installed so not very useful if you want a web app.

However Word documents are storred as XML files inside a zipped file (rename file from name.docx to name.zip to see the files) so you could always write a class to read in the XML and display it inside a Rich Text Box and then after formatting write it out to a XML form, this will take **a lot** of effort.